# Configuring consumer for custom component in apache camel using Java

Tags: apache-camel

Suppose I have a Jetty component comp1 and custom component comp2, where comp1 produces an exchange and comp2 consumes it.
How do I get the exchange of Jetty component in consumer of comp2.

So far I have observed that we can obtain it in consumer's poll() method as -
SomeEndpoint endpoint = camelContext.getEndpoint("someURI", SomeEndpoint.class);

but what to configure at someURI and someEndpoint.class ?

if I mention someURI = "jetty:..", then my consumer will not consume message from anyother endpoint, so how to configure it for generic ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must first create skelatal code for your custom component using

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.camel.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=camel-archetype-component  
-DarchetypeVersion=2.14.1 -DarchetypeRepository=https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots-group  
-DgroupId=org.apache.camel.component -DartifactId={YourArtifactId}
```

your component Prefix file is located in this location

```
src/main/resources/META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/component/
```

The name of this file is your component prefix. You provide this name when you generate the project from the first step.

Lets say its name is comp2. Now you simply need to configure your routes in this manner:

```
from("jetty:abc").to("comp2:xyz");
```

Your component's jar must be provided as dependency to the application that configures the Camel Route.

You need to implement the Component Class, Endpoint class, Consumer and Producer class in case required.

Comment: Yes, but if you implement Consumer then there you need to get the Exchange and that what my problem is, how to get the exchange that will give me the message and header of jetty component.

Comment: @Mayank One way of doing this is that you implement createConsumer() in your Endpoint Class. And here you initialize your Processor Class and delegate flow to it; For eg: XyzProcessor prces = new XyzProcessor( params ). Your XyzProcessor will implment process method and will have exchange available.

Answer (score 0):

Spring DSL allow you to do something like this:
in between consumer and producer you can add you custom producer

```
<route>
  <from uri="component1 uri"/>
   your other process code
  <to uri="component2 uri">
</route>
```

Comment: Thanks, but can you also tell how to do it using Java, as I need to do it with Java dsl.